# Restore the accidentally replaced file

Tags: texmaker

My `.tex` file in TeXMaker was replaced by a blank file when I changed the name of the chapter to another name. Is there any way that I can retrieve the old file back? It has much content in it.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) It's not necessary to sign your questions (as there is already a box with your username below it) or to begin them with a greeting.

Comment: If the file was overwritten on a filesystem level, then restoring its contents is hard, if not impossible, and requires special skills. However, you might want to check for backup files (ending with `~` or `.bak`) in the same directory (I do not use TeXMaker). I am tempted to close this question as off-topic as it, though references a TeX-related tool, covers the non-TeX aspect of the tool.

Comment: What does "replace" mean? Did you remove everything in the file and then save it? Did you copy-and-replace a file over your `.tex` file? Also, what system is this `.tex` file stored?

Comment: Actually the chapter name chap1_noG I renamed. But I had opened a another blank file also. I renamed it with the same name but I forgot to copy the contents. it asked if I need to replace the file. I answered as yes. Also I had complied the file after replacing it. It had almost 50 pages of contents. If anyone could help me, it would be very helpful.

Comment: I do not know about version of your Texmaker but in my case I use the version 3.5. It has a backup option.
Go to menu 'Options' and select 'Configure Texmaker', in the opened window, go to "Editor" section and put a checkmark against 'Backup documents every 10 min' option. If it is active, after each save the editor creates a file with 'bak' extension and previous content. The option has already helped me several times.

Answer (score 1):

The best would be if you had backups, or if you are using version control. Otherwise if you still have the file open, you could try UNDO (this has saved me once).

However there are still other options. The data might not actually be deleted yet. Someone who knows the low level disk interface might be able to retrieve it if you haven't done much on the disk since then, or there are companies that provide this kind of service. Here is a link that might be useful:

http://computer.howstuffworks.com/question578.htm